# Enforcing attribute value uniqueness within a given tag, not necessarily across the whole file

Tags: xsd, xsd-1.0

I'd like to validate an XML file against XSD 1.0 and require the values of one attribute to be unique *within* that one element, but allowing duplicates in different tags.

For exemple, I'd like the attribute (`det`) not to contain repetitions within each `<Client>` tag, but I'd like to allow the attribute to have duplicates in different clients.

So, I'd like to have the snipped below to be valid...

```
<Client id="1">
  <RiscSoc det="01" av="01"/>
  <RiscSoc det="02" av="02"/>
  <RiscSoc det="99" av="02"/>
</Client>

<Client id="2">
  <RiscSoc det="01" av="01"/>
  <RiscSoc det="02" av="02"/>
  <RiscSoc det="99" av="02"/>
</Client>
```

... but not this one below:

```
<Client id="1">
  <RiscSoc det="01" av="01"/>
  <RiscSoc det="01" av="02"/>
</Client>
```

Can that be done with XSD 1.0 (which is the version used in the software I have available)? How?

I've done considerable searching but I can only find examples of `unique` and primary keys to enforce uniqueness across the whole XML file.

Thanks!!

Comment: You probably know this already, but this is definitely not possible in XSD 1.0. Are you able to check these rules using XPath?

Comment: I didn't know that (with statistical certainty), but I suspected that it was the case. Anyway, using XPath seems like a good idea. Thanks @kimbert!!